# Why does applying shrinkwrap make my detail go away?

Tags: shrinkwrap

I retopo'd using a subD & shrinkwrap modifier.

Now I want to make changes to the new topology, post-shrinkwrap.

However when I apply the shrinkwrap so I can make those changes, I lose all my detail.

It seems the only way I can keep the detail is to apply the subD first, but of course I don't want to apply the subD.

What am I doing wrong? Why does applying my shrinkwrap make all my detail go away?

[image: I lose all detail when I apply the shrinkwrap]

Answer (score 0):

The modifiers are dependent on the order in which they are placed. The *Shrinkwrap* works good because it has a subdivided high resolution mesh to use for deforming.

However, when you apply a modifier it uses the mesh that is present at the moment it is applied. Since the *Subdivision Surface* modifier isn't applied yet, the subdivided mesh you see is not the real underlying mesh at the time of applying the *Shrinkwrap* modifier.

That's the reason why you get a warning / info in the status bar at the bottom: *Applied modifier was not first, result may not be as expected*:

[image: apply warning]

The problem here is, applying the *Shrinkwrap* modifier is going to permanently change the mesh, it's going from procedural to destructive modeling. But the *Shrinkwrap* modifier cannot change the vertices permanently if the *Subdivision Surface* modifier is not applied and you can still change its resolution procedural. So the *Shrinkwrap* has to use the real existing vertices from before subdividing.