# Shrinkwrap - applying subdivision surface changes the look of the object

Tags: modifiers, uv, subdivision-surface, shrinkwrap

May i have a question about applying subdiv modifier in shrinkwrap?
I have an issues with correct projecting of an image, i found that i might have to apply modifiers and UV project it on final mesh.

But when i want to apply modifs, after i apply subdiv modifiers the look od it changes, the edges of shrinkwrap are no longer smooth. And i cannot find answer what am i doing wrong here.

May I ask you for your opinion?
Thank you very much for your help.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Does https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/283840/why-does-applying-shrinkwrap-make-my-detail-go-away help? (Move the Subdiv modifier above the Shrinkwrap.)